# variable scope within angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angular-services

I have a custom service, which has a dependency on another service and has an external api and some internal functions.

```
angular.module('DashboardApp').factory('layerQueryer', layerQueryer); 

function layerQueryer($http, $q, overlayLayersConf) {
    layerQueryer.$inject = ['$http', '$q', 'overlayLayersConf'];

    function joinArrays(array1, array2, keya, keyb) {
            .....
    };

    function getLayerList() {
        var def = $q.defer();
        var Promise1 = dosomething();
        var Promise2 = dosomethingelse();
        var Promise3 = doanotherthing();
        $q.all([Promise1, Promise2, Promise3])
            .then(function (data) {
                def.resolve('xxxx');
            })
            .
        catch (function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
        return def.promise;
    };
    return {
        getLayerList: getLayerList,
    };
}
```

I have two problems with this service - one when the callback executes after the three promises are fulfilled I no longer have a reference to the overlayLayersConf service passed into the service constructor, which I need, and I also do not have a reference to joinArrays when I need to use it around the same time.

I have found that if I turn the JoinArrays function into a variable and make an additional two functions and expose them:

```
function getJoinArray(){
    return joinArrays;
}

// for some reason this seems to allow the scope to be kept during the promise callback...
function getOverlayLayers(){
    return overlayLayersConf;
}

return {
    getJoinArray:getJoinArray,
    getLayerList: getLayerList,
    getOverlayLayers: getOverlayLayers,
};
```

Then I can get references to these variables. This seems intuitive but strange at the same time. Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're providing `$inject` array inside the function itself... It's not the proper way to do things. It should be provided before function is called

```
function layerQueryer($http,$q,overlayLayersConf){
 ....
}
layerQueryer.$inject = ['$http','$q','overlayLayersConf'];
```

> after the three promises are fulfilled I no longer have a reference to the overlayLayersConf service passed into the service constructor

How do you find that out? Any of the code presented doesn't use `overlayLayersConf`. It means that it won't be saved into closure so in debugger `overlayLayersConf` will be undefined inside all sub-calls.

`joinArrays` in first snippet is a private function. It can be accessed only from the code inside the service only

Comment: I was using the debugger - you were right without a lot to go on so thanks. I hadn't appreciated that the unused code wasn't inserted into closure callbacks but it makes sense. Thanks. Have also put the $inject just before the function - that's what the style guide recommends and is more readable so hopefully that won't cause me any more problems.